# Produce ggplots from lists with stats

Tags: r, ggplot2, split, time-series

This is perhaps asking too much from one piece of code, but here goes:

Can I:

1. Make multiple individual ggplots over a large list of dataframes?
2. Do an ANOVA programmatically across a small set of data within each dataframe in the dataframe list?

I have a very long dataset something like stored in object "a":

```
Volunteer Conditions  Time Compounds Conc
   V1       Cond1     0    HBA      0.2
   V1       Cond1     0    HBA      0.19
   V1       Cond1     0    HBA      0.21
   V1       Cond2     0    HBA      0.42
    ..         ..      ..   ..        ..
   V1       Cond1      4    HBA      0.45
   V1       Cond1      4    HBA      0.45
   V1       Cond1      4    HBA      0.45
   V1       Cond2      4    HBA      0.48
     ..       .     ..       ..
```

This repeats over Volunteers (V1, V2,V3..), Conditions (Cond1, Cond2, Cond3...), Time (0,4,8) and Compounds (HBA, BPA, HPP, BPV...) with about 939 observations in triplicates.

This has been split with:

```
b<-split(a, f=a$Compounds)
```

I want to try and make box plots.

When performed for individual compounds, it works, but can I apply it over `b`.

so something like:

```
ggplot(data = b$HBA, 
       aes(x=as.factor(Time), y=(Conc)))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.5)+
  facet_wrap(Volunteer~Conditions, ncol = 3)+
  theme_bw()
```

works well.

But not for `b[[i]]` or something like that in a ggplot. Is it also possible to automatically produce a ggplot and save it in looped names like plot_HBA.jpg, then the next with plot_BPA.jpg (which is the name of the next compound in the list).

I also want to do an ANOVA across the replicate observations for time points (0,4,8) WITHIN a Compound, WITHIN a Volunteer, WITHIN a condition.

I tried:

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

a%>%group_by(Compounds,Condition,Volunteer)%>%anova_test(Conc~Time)
```

but it simply fails saying residuals of sum of squares is 0.

I want the brackets with p values over the box plots within each facet for statistically significant changes across a time series.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a for loop, but I think it's a bit cleaner to define a function that creates the plots (filtering the dataset by the name of the compound) and then using purrr::map to run the function on each compound name. You could add arguments to the function to, for example, make saving the plot an option in case you don't always want it to save the file.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

#Create a sample data set similar to the example
set.seed(1)
Volunteer <- rep(c("V1","V2","V3","V4"), each = 4, 10)
Conditions <- rep(c("Condition1","Condition2","Condition3","Condition4"), each = 2, 20)
Time <- c(rep(c(0,4,8), 53),0)
Compounds <- rep(c("HBA", "BPA","HPP","BPV"), 40)
Conc <-  runif(160, 0,1)
a <- tibble(Volunteer, Conditions, Time, Compounds, Conc)

#Define a function that creates (and saves) a 
#boxplot for each compound
boxplot_by_compound <- function(df, compound) {
  df %>% filter(Compounds == compound) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Time), y=Conc))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.5)+
  facet_wrap(Volunteer~Conditions, ncol = 3)+
  theme_bw()
  ggsave(paste0("plot_",compound,".jpg"))
  last_plot() #If you want to see it in addition to just saving to file
}

#Instead of splitting the dataset into a list, 
#just get a vector of compound names
compound_names<-unique(a$Compounds)

#Map the list of compound names to the boxplot function
map(compound_names, ~ boxplot_by_compound(a, .x))
```